# Jsx is used without importing react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webstorm, typescript-declarations

I am getting the

> Jsx is used without importing react

Notification by `WebStorm` even tho I made `react` library global via:

My `webpack.config.js`

```
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                React: "react"
            })
        ]
```

My `declarations.d.ts`

```js
import _React from "react";
declare global {
    const React: typeof _React;
}
```

It is no error and the code runs fine, but I do not like such an unnecessary notification. How do I tell WebStorm that I did import `react` globally?

Comment: Try to import the package in this way: `...const React: import("react");` and get rid of the top import.

Comment: I cannot use the rest operator here. Also I would get the error `TS2686: 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didnt express it correctly, the dots are not meant to be copied, I just used them to indicate there is code before. Basically, using an import the way you are doing will prevent the file from being global. Doing it this other way should do the trick. However, at least with VScode, there is no need to do anything extra as long as you install the `@types/react`, `@types/react-dom` npm packages.

Comment: I see! well it does work either way - as I said he code runs as expected. But my `ide` shows me this error. This is `WebStorm` specific.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just turn the inspection off in **Settings | Editor | Inspections | JavaScript and TypeScript | Imports and dependencies, Missing React import with JSX**

Comment: As of October 2020, in the current version of WebStorm (or other JetBrains products) which is 2020.2, the setting is actually moved to:
Settings | Editor | Inspections | JavaScript and TypeScript | Imports and dependencies | Missing React import with JSX

Comment: This isn't a good solution, because now you wont be able to detect this issue when it does come up.

Comment: It's the best solution given the circumstances, especially if you're using Preact or the like as JetBrains refuses to support other JSX frameworks.

Comment: Also useful if you're using React 17 and the new runtime which does no longer require the React import.

Comment: @Citizen you can configure this setting per project and get the warning in other projects if you want to ;)

Answer (score 1):

## September 2022 Update

The setting is now under `Editor > Inspections > JavaScript and TypeScript > Imports and dependencies > Missing 'React' namespace import in JSX code`

To completely disable this inspection, select `No highlighting` as the `Severity` option.

[image: The JetBrains Webstorm code inspection severity settings dropdown]